# Android Fragment/Activity theme switching issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to switch theme between `Activity/Fragment` and vice versa. Our application set theme from Manifest for the application, of course this also apply to Activity and underneath fragment. However, I have a situation where I am expected to set custom theme for the **particular** Fragment. I can achieve this by the adding following in `onCreateView`.

```
requireContext().theme.applyStyle(R.style.FragmentSpecificTheme, true)
```

I am also expected to reset/undo the theme back to actual for the whole app once user exit **particular** fragrant without restarting the application, I been through the following ways to reset/restore the theme back to original but none of them worked.

1. Used following code in particular fragment to set the scope of the theme upto that screen only.

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style. FragmentSpecificTheme);
    //clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(context);
    //inflate using the cloned inflater, not the passed in default
    return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
   }
   ```

2. Use `ContextThemeWrapper` inside `onAttach` of the particular fragment.
3. Use `requireContext().theme.applyStyle(R.style.OriginalTheme, true)` inside ParentFragment to reset the theme of the whole application to original, Also tried with `requireActivity()` context, This works for the some screen but not for all but this isn't the appreciated solution.
4. Use `requireContext().theme.applyStyle(R.style.OriginalTheme, true)` inside `onDestroy` of the particular fragment so same fragment can undo the theme.
5. Setting android:theme = "@style/FragmentSpecificTheme" inside XML of the particular fragment

I appreciate it if one can point out the error.

Comment: How about setting that on the fragment's layout root view `android:theme = "@style/your_Custom_Theme"`?

Comment: @Zain It still not working,I've updated the question with #5. Thank you.